# How can I make two process comunicate?

Tags: .net, named-pipes, inter-process-communicat

I have two .net applications. One is a normal Windows Forms application while the other is a Microsoft Word COM Add-in. I'm developping both applications with C#.

I need theses two application to comunicate with each other. I'm wondering what is the best way to achieve this.

The first thing I though was that I should use a bi-directional named pipe to do this, but named pipes are system-wide and I need the connection to be restricted to process runnings in the same session (This could and will be used on a terminal server).

Is there any way to restrict a named pipe to the current session? If there is not what alternatives do I have?

Thanks

Comment: OK, here's a silly shot in the dark: would sockets work?

Comment: I don't think they would since I would have multiples servers running in differents sessions on the same machine (terminal server setup). How would I know on wich one to connect?

Comment: what kind of communication are we talking about here. Real time, one time, at some interval? What type of data are you sending plain text, objects, xml?

Comment: I need to transmit objects, but I figure I could convert the objects to xml or text. I want the transfert to be instantaneous since the user will initiate the transfer in one application and expect an immediate response from the other.

Comment: Is that "instantaneous" a one time thing or will they be going back and fourth between the applications?

Comment: @Foovanadil: It's an operation that will be repeated multiple times. Anywhere between one and sixty times per hour.

Comment: Does one of the applications spawn the other? If so you could quite easily set-up an anonymous pipe, which would definitely be private.

Comment: @Adrian: They were supposed to be independant, but one could probably spawn the other. If I don't find a better solution this is something that could work.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a local web service to achieve this.

To create your web service you must do something similar to:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebService1
{        
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        public int myInt = 0;

        [WebMethod]
        public int increaseCounter()
        {
            myInt++;
            return myInt;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

    }
}
```

when you run your web service you should see something like:

[image]

### on a different program/thread  (in this case console application)

you should be able to connect to that service as:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Lastly  type the url of the service you just created:

[image]

Now you are able to instantiate an object from that class Service1 from this console application as:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication36
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            localhost.Service1 service = new localhost.Service1();

            // here is the part I don't understand..
            // from a regular class you will expect myInt to increase every time you call
            // the increseCounter method. Even if I call it twice I always get the same result.

            int i;
            i=service.increaseCounter();

            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());

            // you can recive string data as:
            string s = service.HelloWorld();

            // output response from other program
            Console.WriteLine(s);

            Console.Read();


        }
    }
}
```

with this technique you will be able to pass mostly anything to your other application (anything that is serializable). so maybe you can create this webservice as a third thread to make it more organized. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer, you've put lot of efforts in it. However, I resolved this problem a couples of month ago by using a bidirectional WCF service and I think it's a better solution. It's like a web service, but it's hosted within my .net application.

Comment: I got that answer from: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7589301/637142 . just modified it very little. Thanks that is def a better solution that seems very interesting.