# Return object which contains List<object> to web client in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, jax-ws, webclient

I have JAX-WS web method that returns an object that contains list of objects. I am trying to consume this method from asp.net web client. How can I access the returned object? Should I bother about raw xml SOAP response?
Can anyone point out where I should look for the solution to this problem? Thank you

Here's my web method:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "searchPerson")
public People searchPerson(@WebParam(name = "ID") int ID) {
    People ppl = new People();
    List<Person> pDetails= ppl.getPersonDetails();
//my implementation
return ppl;
```

And here's the soap response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:searchPersonResponse xmlns:ns2="http://People/" xmlns:ns3="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Person">
            <return>
                <ns3:person_details>
                    <ns3:id>10012</ns3:id>
                    <ns3:Name>Bob</ns3:Name>
                </ns3:person_details>
            </return>
        </ns2:searchPersonResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

And my webclient:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LookupService.PeopleWSClient client = new LookupService.PeopleWSClient();
            LookupService.searchPersonResponse searchResponse = new LookupService.searchPersonResponse();
            client.searchPerson(Convert.ToInt32(searchTxt.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited. Now on my client side I'm not really sure how should I get an access to the returned result form the webmethod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I just needed to instantiate an object of webservice on my client. Helpful tutorial found here [Sending list from webservice and consume it in application](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/sending-list-from-webservice-and-consume-it-in-application/), and related [How to add web reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589301/instantiating-an-object-from-a-web-service-vs-instantiating-an-object-from-a-reg)